# Splitting a Associative Array Based off if Condition of Value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm combining an array based off a MySQL Query:

```
$newskus = array();
$newqtys = array();

$sql1 = $db->query("//QUERY//");

while($row = $sql1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $newskus[] = $row['SKU'];
    $newqtys[] = $row['Quantity'];
}

$newskusandqtys = array_combine($newskus, $newqtys);
```

This gives me an associative array like so:

```
Array
(
[Product 1] => -1
[Product 2] => 0
[Product 3] => 3
)
```

I'm looking to split this array based off the condition of the integer value.

That is, if the value is above 0, it'll put the contents into a variable `$newqtysabovezero`

Ending with an expected output of

```
Array
(
[Product 3] => 3
)
```

And the other way around, if the value is greater than or equal to 0, put this into an array variable `$newqtysbelowzero` with an expected output of

```
Array
(
[Product 1] => -1
[Product 2] => 0
)
```

I'm able to do this with a numerical array, but it of course is not passing the key:

```
foreach( $newqtys as $item ) {
   if ( $item > '0' ) {
       $newqtysabovezero[] = $item;
   } elseif ( $item <= '0') {
       $newqtysbelowzero[] = $item;
   }
}
```

How would I modify this to get my expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the `array_combine` part, and just read the values into the final arrays as you fetch them.

```
while($row = $sql1->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['Quantity'] > 0) {
       $newqtysabovezero[$row['SKU']] = $row['Quantity'];
    } else {
       $newqtysbelowzero[$row['SKU']] = $row['Quantity'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
foreach( $newqtys as $key => $item ) {
    if ( $item > '0' ) {
        $newqtysabovezero[$key] = $item;
    } elseif ( $item <= '0') {
        $newqtysbelowzero[$key] = $item;
    }
}
```

And here is a method using `array_filter()`:

```
$in = array(
    'Product 1' => -1,
    'Product 2' => 0,
    'Product 3' => 3
);

function at_and_below($v) {
    return $v <= 0;
}

function above($v) {
    return $v > 0;
}

$newqtysabovezero = array_filter($in, 'above');

$newqtysbelowzero = array_filter($in, 'at_and_below');
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, to get all values from the `'Quantity'` field as *integers* you should cast them to *integer* type:

```
...
while($row = $sql1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $newskus[] = $row['SKU'];
    $newqtys[] = (int) $row['Quantity'];
}

$newskusandqtys = array_combine($newskus, $newqtys);
```

Then, you can easily separate values which are *greater than* OR *equal/less than* `0`:

```
foreach (newskusandqtys as $k => $item) {
   if ($item > 0) {
       $newqtysabovezero[$k] = $item;
   } else {
       $newqtysbelowzero[$k] = $item;
   }
}
```